# Create a new dataframe based on old one in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

[image]

The dataframe above is the an example of the original one. I am trying to create following new dataframe based on this original one:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(abundance ~ StationCode + SpeciesCode, df1)
```

-output

```
      SpeciesCode
StationCode AME BCF BKB CAP
       O-01   2   1   5   0
       O-02   1   0   1   1
       O-03   0   4   2   0
       O-04   0   0   8   1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SpeciesCode = c("AME", "AME", "BCF", "BCF", "CAP", 
"CAP", "BKB", "BKB", "BKB", "BKB"), StationCode = c("O-01", "O-02", 
"O-03", "O-01", "O-04", "O-02", "O-04", "O-01", "O-02", "O-03"
), abundance = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 2L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```